# Twilio Fowarding Calls

Tags: node.js, twilio

I create a call IVR-Tracking-Call Foward using twilio Functions and Assets and everything works well i Receive a call, if the call is asnwered i receive a email with my recording, if the call is not asnwered is fowarding to voicemail and i receive a email as well. My only problem happens when the number that the call is been foward to haung up the phone before the person that originate a call. When that Happen the person that originate the call is foward to the voicemail. Im Using twilio function so is all writen in Nodejs.

Thanks for you help

Answer (score 1):

If I am understanding your question correctly, you need to set the [action URL](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#action) of the TwiML Dial Verb. Once the action URL fires, look at the `DialCallStatus` [key](https://www.twilio.com/docs/voice/twiml/dial#dialcallstatus). If it is completed (which means the call was answered), then hangup the call (meaning disconnect the caller).

Here is also a blog which may address other issues you may encounter should the dialed parties voicemail picks (but you want all voicemail centralized on Twilio), so you can verify it is a human who answers the call and not a machine/voicemail.

[Outsmart Voice Mail with Human Detection Using Keypress Prompts](https://www.twilio.com/blog/voice-mail-human-detection-studio-functions)